# About wrap and call C function

Tags: c, lua, closures, ffi

I get this question from this Chinese blog http://chenyufei.info/blog/2011-02-28/wrap-c-function-closure-gcc-nested-function/
The author want to use closure in c language, and he found GCC has the ability of nested function (and closure).
For example:

```
typedef int (*func_t)(int arg);


int foo(int a) {

    return a + 1;

}


func_t create_wrap_function(func_t f) {

    int wrapped(int arg) {

        // call original function

        int val = f(arg);

        fprintf(log_func_call, "arg: %d ret: %d", arg, val);

        return val;
    }

    return wrapped;
}
```

But it is not common solution. create_wrap_function has fixed function format, because the func_t limits the format.

As we know, Lua has closure, and could call C function too.
What I want to implement like:
The functions we want to call is foo1 and foo2, they has different types of args and return value.

```
int foo1(int a) {
    ...
    return intValue;
}

double foo2(char* str, double a) {
   ...
   return dblValue;
}
```

In C client, call the function like:

```
lua_returnValue returnValue1 = Do_Lua_Wrap(__FILE__, __LINE__, foo1, 1);
lua_returnValue returnValue2 = Do_Lua_Wrap(__FILE__, __LINE__, foo2, "string data", 1.2345);
```

In the Do_Lua_Wrap, it will pass the foo1 and 1 to the Lua function, then call foo1 function like normal process.
Then pass the foo2 and one char* and one double value to the Lua function, then call foo2 function like normal process.
In the Lua function, it could log the information about **FILE** and **LINE** 
and write some extra log about function arguments.

But I don't have idea about how to write the function Do_Lua_Wrap in C and Lua, 
Is it possible?

If possible, could you give me some advices?

Answer (score 2):

You are obviously interested in a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), but the trouble is determining the type of the arguments to push onto the Lua stack. I'll recommend a couple approaches:

1. The first would be to include a
   format string a la the [printf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf)
   family or binary packing formats
   often used in higher level
   languages. For example, take a look
   at the format pattern used in the
   [lpack](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lpack) Lua module. The key is to
   scan through the format string to
   determine how many and what kind of
   arguments are provided.
2. Alternatively, you could implement a
   [variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type) type. Each argument
   would need to be wrapped in such a
   structure. Also, the total number of
   arguments would need to be provided
   as the first parameter.
3. Finally, you could pass arguments in two
   arrays instead of using a variadic
   function. The first array would
   contain the enumerated types
   corresponding to the target of `void
   *` pointers in the second array. This method requires the most house
   keeping for client code, but is
   fairly clean. Either an argument specifying the length of the arrays or a sentinel
   value at the end of one or both array would be required as well.

Hopefully, one of those methods should work out for you. Personally, I would go with the first option and use the [lpack](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lpack) code as a guide. It comes the closest to the function signature specified in your question as well.